# How to add a class from an ActiveX Control using Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, mfc, activex, visual-studio-2019

I'm exploring how to make use of an existing ActiveX control in my C++ MFC project under Visual Studio 2019. But Visual Studio deprecated the wizard that can add a class from an ActiveX control (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/adding-a-class-from-an-activex-control-visual-cpp). Does anyone know how to best approach this?

Basically, what I want to achieve is to create a class for each interface that I need from the ActiveX control.

The ActiveX control in question is from TXTextControl.

Best regards,
Keun

Comment: *"Does anyone know how to best approach this?"* Approach what exactly? The wizard has been deprecated. There's no indication, that it has actually been removed. If indeed it has been removed in Visual Studio 2019, just open your solution in Visual Studio 2017, add the control using the wizard, and move back to Visual Studio 2019. Of course you can always manually edit your .rc file to add the control.

Comment: Wouldn't know how to add the control to my .rc file. But your suggestion to open it in an earlier version makes sense. Thanks.